# How to cut an image using a list of points using opencv

Tags: opencv

I have an image, and a selection given by a list of points (a poly). My goal is to get another image where everything except the selection is transparent.

There are two parts to this question:
 * how to create the mask from the list of points?
 * what's the best way of creating the new image using the mask? I was thinking of cvCopy but how can I handle the alpha channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a simillar issue and I solved it in a strange (not very fast) way:

1. Extracted red, green and blue channels of an image (using `extractChannel`).
2. Do a `bitwise_and` operation between each of the channels and poygon mask image.
3. Merged them back (using `merge` function).

Note that if you have one-channel image than you just need to do a `bitwise_and`.

**C++** code:

```
void createPOI(const Mat& src, const Mat& polyMat, Mat& dst)
{
    vector<Mat> array(3);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        extractChannel(src, array[i], i);
        bitwise_and(array[i], polyMat, array[i]);
    }

    merge(array, dst);
}
```

You can create `polyMat` mask using `fillPoly`/`fillConvexPoly` functions (depends on your polygon). For example:

```
Mat polyMat = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC1);
fillConvexPoly(polyMat, polygon, Scalar(255));
```